# Error with adding light in Directx

Tags: directx, lighting, directx-10

I have been reading Intro to DX10 by Frank Luna. I coded my own version of his lighting program and have run into an error. I will post the relevant code(as far as I can see, it is relevant..)

```
            mLights[0].dir = D3DXVECTOR3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            mLights[0].ambient = D3DXCOLOR(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
            mLights[0].diffuse = D3DXCOLOR(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
            mLights[0].specular = D3DXCOLOR(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

            world = trans;
            Wvp = world * view * perspect;
            fxVar->SetMatrix((float*)&Wvp);
            fxWorld->SetMatrix((float*)&world);
            D3DXVECTOR3 eye = { 2.0f, 3.0f, 5.0f };
            fxEyePosW->SetRawValue(&eye, 0, sizeof(D3DXVECTOR3));
            fxLight->SetRawValue(&mLights[0], 0, sizeof(Light));
```

The error is an access violation(0xC0000005) when it tries to set the Wvp matrix. I have looked around and I am pretty sure that this means that my matrix is not filled. Although, when I comment out the line setting the light the program works, I just can't see anything. The question is then, why would the lights cause the world matrix to have an access violation? They should have nothing to do with each other.

If more code is needed, please say so. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT: 
I have added breakpoints and it appears that on the first loop when it is set it goes through fine but then the second loop hits the access violation. So it is clear that when the light is set, the access violation is created.

I get fxVar here:

```
    tech = fx->GetTechniqueByName("tech");
    fxLight = fx->GetVariableByName("gLight");
    fxEyePos = fx->GetVariableByName("gEyePosW");
    fxWorld = fx->GetVariableByName("gWorld")->AsMatrix();
    fxVar = fx->GetVariableByName("gWVP")->AsMatrix();
```

SetMatrix is a function that comes with the DirectX library, it sets matrices in the shaders. The error comes on this line:

```
fxVar->SetMatrix((float*)&Wvp);
```

The problem only comes on this line when I set the gLight in the shader.

Wvp is defined at the top of the class, so that everything can see it.

Comment: paste more code please, where is fxVar? how SetMatrix works? where you  defined Wvp? all tell us which line cause the error.

Comment: @zdd Questions answered in the original post towards the end. Forgot I can comment on my own posts...